# How to add a SharePoint tab using Microsoft Graph API and Graph Client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

This is the example on the docs to add a typical Teams tab via the Microsoft Graph API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs
{
  "displayName": "My Contoso Tab",
  "teamsApp@odata.bind" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/06805b9e-77e3-4b93-ac81-525eb87513b8",
  "configuration": {
    "entityId": "2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "contentUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/tabView",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "removeUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/uninstallTab"
  }
}
```

If you want a SharePoint tab, it says "For SharePoint page and list tabs, the teamsAppId is 2a527703-1f6f-4559-a332-d8a7d288cd88. Configuration is not supported. If you want to configure the tab, consider using a Website tab."

Using the Graph Client library, it's quite simple to:

```
//Add groups
await graphClient.Groups
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(group);
//Add teams
await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
//Get channels
var channels = await graphClient.Teams[ID].Channels
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

But for adding tabs they don't have a helper in the Graph Client library like for other actions shown above.
I'm going off my best guess to add a SharePoint tab using the Graph Client library and have found:

```
await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(teamsTabTest);
```

However, I am not clear how to set up my teamsTabTest argument to match the accepted parameter to include a SharePoint tab. I passed in the argument:

```
            var teamsTabTest = new TeamsTab
            {
              DisplayName = "Home",
              Id = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/2a527703-1f6f-4559-a332-d8a7d288cd88"
            };
```

And when I ran this, the error response I got was:
Code: BadRequest
Message: The navigation bind for the teamsApp was missing in request.

[image: Error message]

How should I configure my teamsTabTest object so I can properly send a SharePoint tab request?

Comment: have you check this to configure your POST data?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamstab?view=graph-rest-1.0
also check this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59820262/2836750

Comment: You did it! The info on that SO link to a previous answer did the trick. Thank you Muhammad! :)

Answer (score 1):

To anyone in the future struggling with this question, thanks to Muhammad's comment above - I found the correct syntax and working arguments that successfully created a SharePoint teams tab:

```
 var teamsTabTest = new TeamsTab
        {
            DisplayName = "SharePointTestTab3",
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "teamsApp@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/2a527703-1f6f-4559-a332-d8a7d288cd88" }
            },
        };
//Using the graph client helper
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
var response = await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs.Request().AddAsync(teamsTabTest);
```